# View popping up/shaded/embosed out of another view

Tags: ios, xcode, user-interface, cocoa-touch

In my iPhone App,

I have one ViewController with View.

Please see image. **It is a mock up.** I want this popping up like effect. The white view is **bit popping up out of** light grey main view. 
I think it has something to do with its border.

```
I applied border with light grey color.
```

What else I should I do.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should give shadow to view in 2 side to get more effective

```
    "YOUR VIEW".layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1.0);
    "YOUR VIEW".layer.shadowColor  = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    "YOUR VIEW".layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
    "YOUR VIEW".layer.shadowRadius=2.0;
```

Comment: If you see, that border has a color of 225, 225, 225 {Light grey} color.       1. Should I apply border then shaddow. as you mentioned. Or I remobve border. And only put a border.

Comment: You can try shadow and remove border.
The main thing is view should be look like as per your requirement.Thank you